# Start hybrid development with Heroku

Tags: node.js, cordova, heroku, salesforce

I finished a website with Rails, Heroku & Salesforce and now i must create the same but as mobile application.

In the website project, Heroku was usefull to access Salesforce data with Heroku Connect and Heroku Postgress. I want to know if it's possible to use them for a mobile app.

I guess no, i did not fount lot of [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/mobile) about it and it's focus on iOs. I want to create hybrid app on Ionic

**Is it possible do to it ?**

Or a second idea is to create a REST API in Node as they suggest [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api) to send Json to a connected mobile app dev with Ionic cordova. Another way to create an app connected to the Salesforce Data

I tried [Salesforce MobileSDK](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/project/mobile-sdk-hybrid-apps/mobilesdk-hybrid-apps-04) but I always encouter issues.

**What do you think is the best solution ?**

if you have some ideas do not hesitate. I'm still "in the sandbox"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can expose your Rails app as REST endpoints that your custom / Ionic mobile app can talk to.  However, if you just want a mobile UI for the Salesforce parts then you can use Salesforce1 or the MobileSDK for custom mobile apps that just use Salesforce.

Comment: I need a custom one but MobileSDK tutorial on trailhead does not work or not exactly like screenshot. So you guess i should add on my first project an API Rails and not create another project in Node ?

Comment: You should report the issue you are having.  Also, if you use the MobileSDK you won't need the Rails or Node API.